# Validate files/archives against database - Are derived clases the correct way?

Tags: c#, file, casting, archive, derived

I'd like to validate files or entries inside archives (zip, 7z,...) against a database by Crc32. 
If files are unknown, delete them. If files need to be renamed, rename them, and so on...

this is the structure that i have implemented so far:

```
public class FileBase
{
    public FileBase() { }

    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Name => Path.GetFileName(FullName);
    public string FileNameWithoutExtension => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FullName);
    public string DirectoryName => Path.GetDirectoryName(FullName);
    public string Extension => Path.GetExtension(FullName);
    public string Crc { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastWriteTime { get; set; }
}

public class FileModel : FileBase
{
    public FileModel() { }

    public void MoveTo(string target)
    public void Delete()
}

public class ArchiveModel : FileModel
{
    public ArchiveModel() { }

    public HashSet<ArchiveFileModel> Entries{ get; private set; }

    public Dictionary<string, Stream> Extract(List<ArchiveFileModel> entries)
    public void Compress(Dictionary<string, Stream> fileStreams)
    public void Modify(ArchiveInfoFile entry, string targetName)
}

public class ArchiveFileModel : FileBase
{
    public ArchiveFileModel() { }

    public int Index { get; set; }
    public ArchiveModel Parent { get; set; }
}
```

I now create a list of type FileBase which contains FileModels or ArchiveModels (based on file extension) to loop though every file and validate against database.

The downsite of this, for every needed action (MoveTo, Delete, Extract, Compress, Modify) I need to cast the base class objects into derived class objects (which I feel is bad practise):

```
var fileList = new List<FileBase>;
.
.
.
foreach (file in fileList)
{
    If (file is ArchiveFileModel)
    {
        var archive = file as ArchiveFileModel;
        archive.Compress(....
        ...
    }
}
```

and so on....

Does anyone have any other ideas to solve this usecase?

Comment: Can't you have those methods (MoveTo, Delete, Extract, Compress, Modify) inside your top level class? And then inside the loop, you can just call them without casting, you'll have to override them inside each derived class tho.

Comment: that sounds like a easy solution. but what about e.g. FileModel? that class shouldn't be allowed to Compress or Extract

Comment: You could always create interfaces, and have your derived classes implement them.  For example, consider making an `ICompressable` interface with a `Compress` method, and only the derived classes that implement ICompressable would get their .Compress called (using the `file is ICompressable` syntax similar to your second code snippet).  It's more extensible than checking derived types, as you can now create as many derived types as you want, and you never have to update your original code.